# C# WFA Have open file dialogue show on a list

Tags: c#, file, checkbox

So, using my openFileDialog with Windows Form Application - I have it so when I click a button, it allows me to select a file which is the following code.

```
    {
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "Desktop";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Mod Folder";
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Then I got my list where I want the selected file to show up and the person using the program can check boxes for which individual program they want.

I'm not exactly sure what I should put into the list

```
        // checkedListBox1
        // 
        this.checkedListBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        this.checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;
        this.checkedListBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.checkedListBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 40);
        this.checkedListBox1.Name = "checkedListBox1";
        this.checkedListBox1.ScrollAlwaysVisible = true;
        this.checkedListBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(217, 304);
        this.checkedListBox1.TabIndex = 8;
        this.checkedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        //
```

I'm using **Microsoft Visual**

Answer (score 0):

The list is pipe delimited.

C# Files|c#|VB Files|.vb

You may reference this for more information...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx